# Problem implementing IRenderingExtesion Interface

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

How do I implement EXTENSIONS for SQL Server Reporting Services?
I need to implement rendering extesion for following things:

1. apply localized text to reports.
2. apply datetime and decimal format based on current culture to reports.
3. use defined background images if any report has been assigned any.

I have tried implementing an IRenderingInterface for SQL Server 2008 R2. 
But it gives me following while connecting to reporting service:

"Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010+MissingEndpointException: The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'."

Following is the renderer class that inherits the IRenderingExtension & implements the required Render and RenderStream Methods along with LocalizedName property:

```
public void GetRenderingResource(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStreamCallback, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection deviceInfo)
{
  //Render any Embedded Resource in the Report
}

public void SetConfiguration(string configuration)
{
  //Used to pass configuration from Reporting Services Config File
  //to this Reporting Serivces Extension
}

public string LocalizedName
{
  get
  {
    //A Read only properties which return the name of
    //this RS extension
    string p_strName = "Custom Renderer";

    System.Globalization.CultureInfo p_CultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

    //Determine the text to be returned (displayed) by
    // the Name property of CultureInfo class
    if (p_CultureInfo.Name == "zh-CHS")
    {
      p_strName += " (Traditional Chinese)";
    }
    else if (p_CultureInfo.Name == "zh-CHT")
    {
      p_strName += " (Simplified Chinese)";
    }
    else if (p_CultureInfo.Name == "en-US")
    {
      p_strName += "(Traditional English)";
    }
    return p_strName;
  }
}

public bool Render(
    Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.Report report,
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reportServerParameters,
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection deviceInfo,
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection clientCapabilities,
    ref System.Collections.Hashtable renderProperties,
    Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream)
{
  System.IO.Stream s = createAndRegisterStream(
      report.Name,
      "html",
      System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
      "text/html",
      true,
      Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.StreamOper.CreateAndRegister);
  System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(s);

  sw.WriteLine("<html><body>");
  sw.WriteLine("Testing IRenderingExtension.");
  sw.WriteLine("</body></html>");
  sw.Close();
  s.Close();
  return false;
}

public bool RenderStream(
    string streamName,
    Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.Report report,
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reportServerParameters,
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection deviceInfo,
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection clientCapabilities,
    ref System.Collections.Hashtable renderProperties,
    Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream)
{
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help...

Point 2 can be covered by using `=User.Language` in the [Report Language field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493.aspx)

Comment: problem resolved now I am working on localizing the text on the report. How do I do it?

Comment: can you please show an example to implement the render method? I want to implement my own render but the official documentation from SSRS does not help much.
When I try to read/write the strem resulting of createAndRegisterStream, I always get the error "Cannot access a closed Stream".
Thanks!